# vim highlighting: remove syntax keyword

Tags: vim

One of the vim plugins I use does:

`syn keyword rustTodo contained TODO FIXME XXX NB NOTE`

Resulting in highlighting `NB` in comments, which I don't like. Is there a way to either redefine the keywords or remove one from them? Looking at `:help syn-keyword` makes me think that this is not possible.

Comment: What plugin manager do you use ? You can try to fork plugin repo, apply your patch and connect fork in configuration file. But it may be an overkill.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If that is the only definition for `rustTodo` (these are cummulative), you can remove and then redefine it:

```
syn clear rustTodo
syn keyword rustTodo contained TODO FIXME XXX NOTE
```

Unfortunately, the granularity for removal of syntax items is limited to whole syntax groups (here : `rustTodo`); you cannot pick individual keywords unless they also have separate groups (which would result in much more linking of highlight groups and therefore inefficient).

To make this permanent, put it into `~/.vim/after/syntax/rust.vim`

If you think that the majority of users doesn't like `NB` here, please suggest to the author to drop it. Adding it back as a personal customization is easier and more maintainable than removing it...

Comment: This is not really an answer, just a work around. I have the same problem and this work around isn't acceptable for me. I really need to just remove one existing keyword.  Ie, something like 'syn !keyword rustTodo NB' (note the '!'). Is that possible?

Comment: The after directory was expressly added for such customizations, so I would say it's more than a workaround. Something cleaner and more maintainable is possible, but would require changes in the original syntax script (i.e. defining a config variable instead of hard-coding the keywords).

Comment: Well, my remark "not really an answer" is more technical ;). If you'd edit your answer and add "No this is not possible (the best you can do is..." then it would be. I'm still unclear now whether this is possible or not (although it seems that it isn't from what I read so far).

Comment: Ok, I'm a bad reader it seems. The question in the title is what I needed, but OP explicitly says "Is there a way to either redefine the keywords or...". Either way, thanks for your super fast reply ;)!

Comment: @CarloWood Don't worry. I've expanded my answer so that it's clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question while importing syntax files from within other syntax files, and came up with a dirty hack.

Instead of loading your syntax file with

```
syn include @othersyntax syntax/othersyntax.vim
```

you can use

```
syn include @othersyntax !sed 's/<NB>//' syntax/othersyntax.vim
```

Eww. This brings serious platform dependency and security issues, but at least relieves you of the burden to keep the replacement keyword list in sync with upstream.